# Trouble reading very long string in R

Tags: r, string

I have this string below which I wanted to run in R, but for some reason it's not able to read. what could be causing the problem?

`mychar<- "AAAGATGTTTTCATTAATCAGTGAACGAAAGTTAGGGGATGGTACTCTTAGGGTTGATCTATAAAGATCCTAACTAGGAGGAAACATGGCCCTGTCTCGTGATGATTTCTTTGTTCAATCACTAAAGCTTCTCTTCACCAAAAAGGAGAGAGCTTTGAGAGCTTAGCTGTTTCAGCTATTTGAACCCCGAAGGATTCATGTCATAGACATTTGACTTCTATTTGAAGTCGTTCATTCGTTCATCCGAAGATGTAAAACTACTGCGCATGTGCGTGATGGTCCTGAATTTTCAGAGTAGAACGGCAGGGATGATTGTTCTGTGGAGTAGTGCCCTAGAAGAACAAATCCTCATTCCCACTCTTGAAAGTGGCCCATGGCAACCCGTGATGCCCGGATCGTCTTCTGGACGTAAAAGGTTAGAGGCTACGAGAGACTGTAGAGACCTTGGTCAAAATGTCCGGCGATCCCGTGCATGGAAGCCAAGGGGGCACGCTCCCCCTTGGAAATAGACCAGTGCGTTTACAACGTGAACTTTCACAAAATAAACAAATTCAACTTTTCCCTTCTCCTATTGCAAATGGTTTCTGCTATTCGCAATTATTCAAGCCAGAATTTCGCACTACCGTGCGGAGCCTTCTGAGGGGCCCGGAGCCATTACTTCGGGATGTGGTCGATGTTCTCGACAAAAACAGGCTGTGGGCCAATGACAGAGATTTTGCCTTGTGTTGGAGCCACAAGGGATCGAAATTGTTGATCCATATTGTACCGCGTCGTTTCTGGGACCCTCGCCCGGTTGTCTCTCACGTCAATTACGCTTTGTCAATAAGGCATCACATACAAGCGAACTTTGATGTGACGAAGTTGCTGACTAGAGGAGGCGTGCTCAGGAGGGAATCATTGACTGTCCCGGAGCAGGCAGTCCCGCAGATCATTGAGCCGGCTGTGCCAGCTCAGAATACAATCACTGATACTGAAACGTTGACGTTTACTATCAATGTGGCAAAGGCATCCGAGAAGCCTACACTTTCTCTCGAGACAAAGTCCGTGCCAGGACAGAAGGAATTGAGGCCCTTCAGCTTTCAGGAGGCGATGACGCCAGCGGTATCTGAGTATTCAAACTTCTTGAATGATCAACCGAAGACGAACTCCCCTTACGACGATCCATTGAAAGATGATCCGATGTCTGCAGGTGAGCAATCACTTAATGACATTTTGGACAAGTCCGCCACTACCTTTGGCGGGATTCAACTCAAGATGGAACAACGTAAAGGATGGACTCAGAAAGAGATCATTCAAGCGATGCAGAAAACCGGCATGGCGCCCAAGCATGCCACGCCTTTCAAGATCCCTGAGGTAGAAGCGAGACGTGACAAGATTAATTCTGCGACTTCTTGCCTTTATGATGCGCTTGAGCCGATGCTTGCAGACACCTACCATGCAGTTCTAGATAAGAAGATAACTCGTATAGGTGACATGCCATGGTCTATGTACCGCTACGCGTCCTGGCTCGCGAACGACAAACGGCAGGATGAAAGGTATTTCTTGATCAAAGTGTCTGTCACGAATGGATTGATCACTCCAGGAGGCACGCCCTCACTGGAAGACCATATTCAATACATCGGGACGTACAAGATGATCAAGAATGCCGGCAGTACCTATTTGCCTTTGGGAATCCGGCCTTTCGGGGATATGAAGGAGAGAATGACGAGTGATGGTACAAGTCTCACGATGCTAATGAAGGGCTCTGAGATTTTCCAGATGAATCCTAGAGAATGCACAATACGCAAGAGCATCCGATTCGCCCATAAATCGCCATTCGTCAGGTCTAGTTGTGTTGATTGCAAAGGTGAGGGAGTTGCTAAGGCCAAGTCTTCACACGGAAAGTTCAACGGACAAGGTCATATGAAACTCTACCCTACTGTTTCTGGCTTCCGATGCCGTAGGTGCAGGGACGACTTCAATGAGTTGCAATGCGCAGGACAAGAACTGACTGAACGCCTGAAGAATTGTTCCTGTGACATGATGTTCAGGATGGAGCATGAGGGCACCCGCTATCATCAGTCATCTTGTCCCCACCTTCATATCATAGGAAACCTTCTTTGGGTAGAGCCAGACACTTCGGATGAGTCTCTATGCGAGGAGGAGTACTGTAGGCCATGTGAACAAGGAGATTTCTGTGAAGAGCACAATGACCCATCGCAGTGTGATTGTTCACAATGCGATGCCGGGGATAGATGCATCCGAACAGGAGAATTTTCAACTCCTCCTGCTGTGTGCCCCACTTGCTCAGAGTCATACAGAAAGACACATTCCTGCGCACTCAATTTCCGACAATTGCAACCTTTTGTGTTAGACCCCGAATTGGCCGTGCCCGAACTGGAATTTGGTGAGGACTCATCCTCCTCTGACGATGACTCAGAAGGAGAGTTGCTTGCGTTGCGGCGCTCTGCGTTCGAGATGGCACCTCCTTCAGAGGTCGAGAGAGCAATCTTCCAGGCCCGGATTGCTAAGTTGAACCGGAATATTGCCTCTCCACCGACTGAATCTTATCAGATTGTCATACTAGAAGAGGAACCCGCAAAGGAAGACGACTCTCGTGTGATTCTCGAATTCATTGAGAGAGAGAGGAAACTCGCGTCAGAGCGAGCGACTGCCATGGCAAATTTGCAATCCTGCTTCCAGAAGGCAAGGCGTGCCTACGCCTTCAAGCCTATCAAAACTGTCTTGAGCGAGGCTATCAACAGGAGATCCGCCAAAGCCAATGGGAAAATCGCTGTGTTGGGCTGGGAAGACCGTGAAGAGATTGAAACAAGGCTCGCTGGCCACAATCAGCTGAAATGTGATCAGATCTGGAATCTGATAAAACCAAGGGTAGAACAGGCAAGGCCTGTCCGAACGAATATGTCAGCAAGTGCTGGTATTCAGAACTGGAAACTGCCAAGTGGCAGCAAAACATACTTGCAAAGGATGGCGGTCCAGGCGAGAATCGATGAAGCCCGTGATCCATTCAATTACCTTTCTAAGGCGACAGTTACCGCAGAGTACACTTGGTCTATATCTGGAAAGCTTCGCAACAAGAAGGCCCACACACTCAATGGGAACGGTCCAAAATGGAGTTACCGTCTCGCAACACCAGACCTTAGGGTCTTTGAGGGGTCTAGTCCGGCCCAGCGCCCAACCTTCTGGGTAGAAATTACTCGAGAATCCAATGGCCCGATGCTAGCTGGTCAATTGTTGACAGAGTTGGGCACTCGCTCTGCCCCAGCACCCCTTATTGATGCGATATTGGAAGAAGCTGTGCCTTCACAACTTTTCAATCTCTCAAAGATAGGGGCTGATGATTGGTTGATCACTCCGGAAGATAGTCCTCACCGTCTTGTTGATGATATGCCCCCGCCTGACAAAGTGAATGTTATCCAATTCCATGGACTCAAGGCCCAGCGAAATCTCGAAAAGGCTTGGGCTCAGATTGCAATCTTGGAAGCGAAGGATCGTCAGAGTACCCATAGGATCTTCCAACTTTCAGCTGCAAAGTGCGATGCACCCCAGGATCATGCGGTACTGGCTAGGACTGAACGCTCCAAACAAGACCTGGAGATGAGACTCCAGGCGAGCATGCAGTCCAGATGCCCTGCACCATCAGATCACGGTCAACTTGCTGAGCTACTAGCTGACCGGAGTCAAGAAGAGCCCTGGAGAATCTGCGGGCATACCCATGAAGATTTTGCATCCCCAGAATTGTGTCAAGAGGGATGTGAGCACACGCCGCTAAGCTTCCCGTGTGACATGCTCCATTGCTATGATCCGCAAATACATGTTGATCCCAATAGAGCCTTTTCACAATGGGGGATGAATGCTGACTACTATCATCCTAGCCCTGATCATTGTGCGCCATGTGAAAAGCCCCATGGACCTATTTGCCCGGATGTTGCTCTGCATGAAACAGCCAAGTCGACAATTAGCTATCTGAGAAAAATTAATGCTGAGCTGACTGGCAGATTGCGTCACATTGTGCCCCCTGAAACTGGGCAAGCGAAAGCGAGCATGAAGAAGAGAATCACAGCCGCCAAGTCCTCTATCCATGCCTGGCATCAAGAATCCTTCAAAGGGCCTAGAGACATGCACTCGAGGAAGGCAACTACTGTGTTGTCCTCTTTGATAGCTGATCTTGATCCAGATGTGCCGCCCTTACCACCGCCAAACAGAGTGCTAGTTCCCAACGTCGTTGATCGATGGTGGAACAAAGCAAACTTGAAGCTTGATGTTAACGGGCAGTATTTCAACTTTCATTTGGCTCAGAGGAAGTTGAGGTACCAGACAGAGGCAGGGTTTATTGACTGGGACCCTTCGCAGGAACGGCTTGGATCGCCGAAGTCTTTAGTAGCGCATTGGAGTTTATTGGAGTATGCTTTTGATCACATTCGTGATCCTTTTAAACAGAAACAGCTGCTGGAACAGCTAGATATGGATTTGGAGACTCTGCGCAAGTGCGCGAGAGATGCTGCCTTATTGCCCTATGATTCGATGACAAGACGCAACTACTTGCGGAAATGGGACCGTGCGACCACTAAGCCATCAGACCCTGGGCCGATCGATCAGACACTGGCAAAGGCTATTGAACTTCTTGATTGTTTAGTGCCGGTGCCAAACAAGCAAGTGTGGAAGACTTGGGATCGTGCATCTGACGAGGGAAAGACTTGGGAACATGGTGGATATAGATATGGACGGCACGCTTTGTCTCCTAGACAACATCATCTTGACGATGAGCTATTTTCTGAATCCCTGGAAGTGTATGACAAGGTTATTCTTGACATCAAGCGCTGGCTCCCCTCCTTGTCTGCTTTCTGTCTTAAGTTTCAGAGCATTACCGTGTGCGCAGGAGGGACAGGCTTATTTAGGTCAAAGTTGGCCGAGTCACAAGCTCTTGTGATCTTTTCAGATGTCCCGTTTGCGGCACCTGGGGGGAACACTCTCGTTGTCTGCCCTGATCCTGAGGTATTTAAAGGCAGAGCACGCGCTTGTCTTCGAGTTCTTCTGCCCATTCTTGTTCCTGGACCACGCTATTACATTGTCAATGGGCGCCTCTACCCCATGGGAACATTCTCAGAAGCCGTCATGCCGAAAATAGCCGCCGATTATCCCTATGGCAGCATCGCGATGCAAGGATTCTGGTCTGCCTATTTGGGAGCGACATTTATCAATGGGGACCCTTTTCCGATTGACCGTAAGTTGAAGGCAATGGCACATTTGCTTCGCGGTATGGATGTCTATGGACCAGACGAGACAGCATTGATGATGTTAGGTGACCCTTGGCCATGTCACGTTGCGTATCCCTTTCAAGGCAATGATGTCAATTACGGCCACGCCCCATGGACTATCCTCCCCGCAGGCAAGACATATGTCCACCTCAAGACGGGGACAGAGGTTGTCGAGTGGCGAGGAGGGTATAATGCGTCAATCTTGGTAGACCATCTCCGTGTCTACAATCAAGTTCGAGACATAAGGGAATTCGGGGTTCCGCACTTCACTGCGCTTGAGATAGAGAATGCATGGGAAATGTCTCCTTCAGGACGAGCATACGAGTGGTTTTCTGAATATCTGAGATTGGTATGGCAATCTTCAAGCCAGGCCTGTTACACAGGACACATCGATATTCAAACAGAGAGGTTGTCATGGGGAAAACCCTGGCTCAACGCCCTGCCAATGCCTCCCTGTGGCACAACAGAAATCAATTGCTCGATCTCCAAGGACGGAGCTGCAGTCTGCAAGATGTTGAAGATACCTCCCATCACCGATTGTGAACTCATTGCTTGCTCGCGTGACAGTTTCAAAGTGTCCAAATGCAGATTGCCAAAACGTATTGTCAACAGGTGTGGCCTTCCTTTTATCACTTTTGGTCTGGCAATGCACAACGACGAGACCACCTTATTCCGCGGCGTAGATCGAGAAGGGATTCATCACACCAACTTTTGTGAATTCCGGCAGGAGCCCCCACCTTGGCTCACTGATCTCGTGCGAGAATTGACCAAGTTGTGCGCTGGCAAGAGGGTAATTGTTACGGCAAATCCGAACTGCAAACCGCCTCGAAAAAACCGTGTTTGCCTCAACTTTGGCGAAGAAGTAGCAGGATGGCATACCGTCAACGTACCAAGAACAAATGGATATGGCGGCCGATCGTTGGCTTTCTGGAGATTACTTGCTTTGTACGTCAAGGCATCGGATGTTTGGATAGTCAATGGAAGGGACACTGCAAGGCAGATCCAGCCCAAGCTAATATCAGGCAGATTTCATAGCGCGAACCAGCATAATGCTATGCCTATAATCTTGGCCAGCACGATGACCGACATCAACTTTCAACCTGCTTGTCCTTCAGCCGATCTTTCATCCTGTACCTGCAGTATTGACAAGAATCCCTGTCTAAGGTTGTTTTTCGGAGCAATGGTCTTGTATGGTCAGACGTATGGTATAGATGAATGGTTTTTACATCGACAGCCACTCACTTCGACTCATTACCATCAGTTGGCAGACAATGACTATCGGATGTACCCTTTGAGTCTCGAATTTCCAGATACCGAATTGATAGAACGCGGTACCACAATCTGGAAAGGCCCCCTTTCTCGCTTCTTGTTACTACAACCTCGTGCGCATGGCCCGGAGGGCACTACTCTTGGATGTGCAGGCAGGGCTCTTCGGAACCGCTTTGACTCCTGGCTTGCGGATATTCCTTTGGTGTATCTTGATTCGCCTTATGCTAAGCCACCAACGCCGAGGTCTGACACCATTCTGATGGTAGTCCATGGTACACGAGGCGACAGAGTGCCTGTTGAATACCTGGCCAGAGTGCTCATAAAGCAAGGGCTCAAGGTCGTTTTGTGGCAAACTTCAAACATGGACTCACGGACACTTGCTAGATTGAAGAATTCAGACTTTTCAGGACAGTTTGTTGATTTTCTTGCAGCTGCTGGTTGCCACAAACTGGGGTATAAGCTGGTGTTTACACCTCATGTTAGTTTGTCTTTGAGTTCCATCAAGTATACTCTTACGAATTGGTCGAATACCAAGACCCCCTCGTGGCTAGGCAATCCATTGGCGCACCTCTCTGTTCTGTTAATGAGAAGTGTTGGGCAGGGTCTCATTGTTGGAAGCACCCCTGGCTGTAACACCCCATATTCAGGCGATGGTCTGCGCTCTCTGCTCTGGTCTGCGCCTCTATCTATTACCCCCGCAGCTCACAACAGGTTGCCTGCCGCATGGGTTGAGTCATCTGATGGACAAGAAGCTATGCCAGAGGCCATCCGTCTTGGATATCCTGGAATCACCATCCCGTATGACATGAGTGAGTTCTCCAAATACAAGAAGATATACACCAACGGTACTCAGGGCACAGTGAACGCTATCATTGCTCATGGCGCTGAGGCAATTGTGGTCGATGCATGGTTTGATCAGGCTCGCACGTATCATATGGAGCCAAGGATCTTCACTGAGTGTACCTTCCAAGCCTTGGGCGATGCACTATGGTCCCGAGGTGTCAAGACGGAACTCCCAATCTCATGGTTTTGGATGCGATGGAGGACATGGGTGCCTACGCAGAAGAGATGGTATCAATATATGGCCATGGGATTAGCTGCTTTTCAATATGTTTATCTTTTGGCGCCTCTCGCTGGAACTTTCCCATCGTTAGTGCGATGGGTTCCTAATAATGTGGCAGTGACCCAGCCAGTGCTGAGGACACTTTTGAACTTTCCAATTATTCACTATTTTTTAGGAGTACGGAGTATTGCATACTTGTTTATTTTTTGGTATGTATTGGAACAATTGCCCATAATGGCATTAGGCATGAAAGAAGGCGTGGTACTGAGAGTTTCTGTTGAGAAGCACTGGATGCCTTTGAAACATGCCAAGATAGTCCACAAGAGGCGTGGTCTCATGATAGAGTATGGCTGGTTCGGTGAGCGTAACCTGATGACACCCTTTCAAGGAAGGCTCTGGAAGCACGTCCCTGAATGTCACAATACAGAGATCGAAGTCCCGATATCCATCGATTTCGATGCTTTAGCGAAACAATGTGTCCATGATGTCTCGGCTTATGGCCCGTTTTTCAACTGCCAAACACAGATTCTCACTAATATTGGAAATAACGCTCCTGCCATCACATTGCTTTGTCTGGGCATATTCTACGCATGGACATTTGTGTTAGCCCCATGGCTTCTTGTTATCTTCATTCATCATGCAGGAATAAAGATTGCCGGGCGTTCTCCCTTGCAATTGATCACTTTAGGTCCGCAGGAAGACAATATCGCGGATATTGCTCTTGGCGCGGCTCTTGATGAAGATGATCTTCCAGATGACGATGGCAGCAATCAACCGGCCATCTTCCAAGATGATGGGACACTTGCATCTCTTAGTGAATTGCCTGATGAAGACCTGATGAGGTTGGCCCTGTTGGCCGCAGTTGAGGAAGACCCAGATGCACCGGAGGACTTGCACGTTGAAGAGGCTGGCCGTATGCTGACCGCAATGCAACAAGAACTCCTTGATCAAGTACAAGTCTACGAGCCCATCGAAGGAGATACTTTCTCTAAATGGTTAGATGAATTCACCTCATGGTGCCTCAAGGAGTTGAGAAACAAGGCTAACACTGTTCCTTATCTGAGGGACATTGTTCGCTTGCTGCTTGCAGTTCAAGATAATTTCTATCGTGTTCTAGAACCGCTTTTCCAGGCCTTGAAGGGTGCATTTGATTCTATGGTGACTGTTTTAGCCGATGGTTCTGAAGCATTCATCCGATTCTGCCACCGGCTTGTTGATCTATTGTTTACCAAACAAGTTACACGCAAGCTCAAGGCTGCATGGTTTGGAGCTGAACTTCTGAAACCCCACAAGCTGTCGATCCAGAAGCGAATCCGTGAGAATCTTTCGATGGCACAAGTCCAAATGGCCGACAACTTCGATGAGCAGTATGCCTTGGACACACGCACTCTTAGAGATGAATATTCCGACGAGGATGTCAACTGGCAGAAGCTGAATGCCATGTCTGAAAATAACACATCCAAAAAGAAATTCAACCATCGTGGTCCCAAGGGGTTTGGAGGTCCAACTTACACCCCTGTCAAACTGCCGAGAAGTCTCGTCCTCAGTCACCAAGAATTGGAAGTCCTTGCCAATGAGGCTTTTAAGGAAGGAGTCGATTTCAACGCCAGGGCTGACCAATACTTCACGAAACGAGTTGATCGTCTAATGTCCAATGGAACGCCGTTAGCCACCGATGGCGCCCTTCTCGCCGCAATCAGGCCGTCCCAGGCCGAGTCATCTCTGATAAGATACACTCATCATGGCGTGGATGCTAATGACCTCTTAAGAACAAATGTTGACCCTTTTCCACCTGAATTGAAAAGTCGTCTTGACGCTGTTGGAGATGCCCTCTACCGTTCAGCTCCAGAGATGCTCAGCGATCCGAAACTGACACCTCCTGAAGCGATGCTTGAATGGTGGCGTCACCGTGGTATGGAGAAATTCAATACCACTGCCCCTCTCAATATGGCTTCAAGAGCACATGCGATCGTTGACGGGCAAATGGCCGCCATACTCAGGGATGTCTACCATAAGGAGAAACAAGGTGCGTACCCTTCTCAATACTATGCCGCAAAAGTGAAAGGACAGGCAGTGCCGGTGGCACCACTAGTCACACCCAATGCCGACGGGCTGTACAAGCCTGTCAGAACTTTTGTTGCACAAGATTCAAGGAGTACAGCTATTGACTGGACGGTGGGATTGGAATTGAAGAATCGTCTGCCAGGCGACCATGTCGGAATCACTTCCAAGATGGCAGCTGGGCAGGGATACTCAAATCTGTTCCGGCGAATCAGAGGCAAAGAGAACATCTTCATGGGTGACATGGGGCAATATGACAGTCGTCTTGAAAGGGAGCATTTCTACATGCTAGACCGAGCTTTGGAGAACGGCGTTTCAGATAAGGTAGTTTTGTCATGGCTTAAAGCAAAGCATGAAGCCATGCAAAATTCATACATAGCGGTTCTCTCATTGCCAAGGGGCAAGGAACTCTCTCCCTTTCTGCAACATGCTCGAGCTAGCAATCGTGATGGACCAAAAGCCCTCCCCGGATATGAAAACTGGATACTGAAAATTCGTTCGGGAGCCACTGGGGAGTCCTCGACTGCCTGGACTGACAGTTGGACATTCAGGGCAACATTTTGCCTTATTGTATGGGATTATTGTGACTATTTTTCAATCCCATTTTCCCCTGATGACTTTTTCAATGATTCTCTAATGAGGCTTGATAATTCAGGCGATGACAACATGGGGCATCTAGACTTTCTCAAGAAGTATGGCCATGTGTTGAACCCTCAAGTAATGGTAGCCTGTGCAAAGAATCGCAATATGACCCTTGACTTTGCAGTCTTGGACTCTTTTGAGAAGTGTGAATTCCTCGGATGTATGGCCAGAGAACCAACTGCCATGGACAAGAAGACATTGGAGCGCGTGAGAGCCCTCTTCCATGAAGCGAAGGTGCGACCTGATCTTGTGAGATATGCAGCCATCAATCCTGATCTGAACGATCCGAACACTCTAGAGGCCCCTGAGATTGTCATCTACAGAAATCTTACCAATTCCTTGGTTCGTCAGACAGCCACCCAGATGTATGGGAATGTTTACAAGGATGACCAGTATCTAGAAAAGTGGATCGCCAAGTATGTCGGACACTTACAGTTGTGTGCCTTCAAACCTACCCATCATCAGGACATCATGCATGAGTATCTTCAGACCTCAATAAGGTGGCTCTATGCTGCAACTGAATCACCTGTAAGAGATCAGCAGGGCATCGTGAAGTTACCGGTTGGACAGATCTACGATGACATCCTTGCTTGCATGAACATCCAATACGAGGATGTCGGAAAGCGTGTCATTTATGCAAAGCCTCTGTCGAAAGCACCTGGAAATCTTGCGAATTCATCAGCCTTCAACACAGAGTTCAGGAGGCGGCTTTTGCGCCTGTCTCAGACTCCTCCAGCTGCTTATTCCAAGGTCATCGGTATACACATGGCTTATGGCAAGAAGCCCGCCTCATTTTATGAGAAAAAGATGCACAAGATCTTTTCAGGCCTCTATCCTATCGATGACGCCGCTAAGGAACTTTTGGATACTCTCCGTTCTGTCATAGGAGAAGCCTCGAGAAAGCTGATAAAAGGCTTCACAGCTCAGGCAAGAGACCAGATGTACCTTGAAGACATTTACGACAGTGGTCATTACTACGTAGAATCAGCCATCTGGCTGACCTATGAAGAAAAGATCATGTCCCAAGACGGGTACGATCCCGAAGACGGCGTCCCTGAAATGTCATTGAGCGTGTGGCAAGGCCTGTGCTCTAAGGCAGCCTTCGGTTCGATTACTGATCCTTTGAGGTATTTCTCACTGATGCAAGACAATGATTTTTCTGACAAGATACGGGCCGAACCTGCTGCTACATATCGAAACATGATGTGGGTTCTAGTCCTCTCGTATGTCCTGCTCTGGTATGTGGAGACTAGGCTATATGGGATCCCTGTTCTCGGATTTCTGTATGCCCTCTTCATGTTCTCAGTCATAGATATGTCGAAGATTTATGGTCTTATCAGCATGTTGTACTGGCTCGTAAACATGGACGTGCACCCTACTATCAGTTCTTGGATGCCGAGGGATCCTTATGTCCTAGCCAAACGCTTATCAAGTTGGAATCTAAAGTTTGTCCCATTATGGTTTGCTCGTTACCTTCCCTTTGCCCATTTGGGCATTCTTCTTATAGATGGTCTTGTCATGTTTTCAAAGTTTTACAATCGTTTGCAGTCTATCAAACCTTTAGCTGGACATGGGTCGCCAATTGATAATCCTTGGACTCGGGATGCCCATCGCATGGTTGAAATGCTCCTCAATGACAAGGTCACTCCTGACAATGCGATCGTTCTTAGCTCTGAGACTGGAACTGGCAAGTCTTCACTTGGGGTGGATGCTATCACCAGGATGATAAAACACGAAATCGCACCCATATCTCGGACATGGGTTTTCGTGCCGACAAGAATTCTATTGAAGGATCCGCTACCAGGCTTTTTGCAACGGGGCGAAGACTCAGACCGCAATGAATCTCTTCGCACATACCAGGTATTGCGAAAAGGGGTCCAAATCAGGTCCAATGCAGAGATTCTCTTCATGACGTACGGTCACGGGAGAAACCGACTTATGAGTGGGGAATTTCAAGATGGAGTGGACACAGCTTTCGTAGATGAGATGCATATCCTCTCAGCCGAGCAAAGGCTAGTTGTCAATCAGTTGAAAGGTCAGCGATTGATATTCTCCTCTGCCACACATGTGCCCCCACCTGGATTTACAGCGCCCGTCTTCAGATCCACGCAAACTAAGAAGTGGAAAGCGATACAGCGAATATTCCCTGCGACTACCAATGTAGCAAGCATGTTTCAAAGAGCCAGAAATGATACCGAACCTATGGCCGGTATGAAAGAGGCACCCGCACAGCTTTCTGATCGCACGTTGATTTTATGTTCAACGTTCAGAGAACTGGACGAGGTGGCCGAATCTTTGACTACATTACGTAAATCTATGTTTGGAGGGGGAATCGGGGTATCGCTGCCACCCGTCGTTGAGATCAGCAGTAGAGTGAAGCCAGGAACAGAAGCATGGTCACAGAGACAAAATGCATTCGTCAAAGGAAGATATATAGCCCTTGGCACGAAGCAAGCAGCCACGGGGATGGACATAAAGCCCTTTCCTCCACGACTCTTAATCGACGGAGGAGAGGATATCTATTCTCACCAAGGCTCAATCTTAAAATTGCCGACTACGCAGAGGGACCATGAACAAAGGATTGGCAGAGTGACAAGGAATTCGGCTACAGGTGATGGACTGGTGTATTGTCGAGAACAAGCTGGAACAAGAGGTTGGGAGACGATGGAGTATCCTTCTTTGTCTTATTTGTCAGAGCAGGTCATAGCAAGTGCTTATGATCTGCCGATGTTGTTTCCAATTGATACGGTGTTAGGCGTTTGTCCGGCCAATAATTATTGGCCATATTTTTCTATCGTAGCAGGCTACGAAAATCACATAATTGAAGCATTGACTTTCGTAGTTTTTGCGAATGCATCAGGGGTCGGGGCCCGCAATATGTCCTCCTTCTACCAGCGCCACTGGCAAAATGGTTTCCCATTGTCCGATGACTTTGAATGGATGGAGACATGCATGAAGCGTCAGGGGTTACGGCCTAACAATACCCCTCCTGCTTGGGTCTCAATAGAAGCAGTGCTCAACCAGAGACCTATAATCTGGAACACGCAACGAATAACAGGGAGCATACCCCTGGAAGTCGAAGGCGTGACCTCTATGGTAAGGTCAAACATTCTTTACCCAGTTGCAGGGTCATATTTGCCTTTTGAACAGGCAATGCAACAAAGAAACAGGGTATTGGACCACACCACACAAGAATCACGGTCAGAAGATATGTCTGCTGATTTGATCGTTAAACTTCAAAAGACAGTGGCCAATCTGTCCAACCAGCTACAATCAAAGGAACAGAAAGGTCAACTCAATACATCGAACACGCAGTCCAATGGATCTTTCACTCGAAGGGAGAAGATTCGACAAGACATTGCCAAGCAGATTGAGTACGTCTTACAGGGAGTTAGCGTGCCAAATGGAGCAAAGCGAAAACGTCAAGACATAATCGCTAAAGATCTGATCGAAAGGTATAGATTCCGGGAACGAGTACCTCAGGCACCATTCGATTCGTCACGTCAATCTGTTGTGACACAAATCATGGACGAAGATGATGGCTGGGGATACTGCACCGCTGACGGAACACCTTTAGTGATCGGTGGGAGTGGTCCAAATGAAGGAGAAACGCCACAGATGAGCTGTGGCCACAACGCTCATTCGCAGGGAAATCATCTGATTAGCGCATCCTTCCATGTCGTAAAACGTGGGGCGGCGTGGACTTCAACATATGAAGTGCAACCCACAAAACAAGTTCTGAATCGTATAATTGTCATGATCACCGATCAAGACATTGACTACGTATTACAGGAAATACAAAGCCACGGAGATAATAGTGAAATTAGGATTGATACTCAATCCGGAATCTCCCGAGGCAGTAGTTCGGCAACCAAACGCCGACGACTACCAGATCTTCTCAAGATGAGCAAGGTCGACCGTTCAAAGCTAATCTGCAATGGTTAGTCACAAGCAAGCTGAAGTTTTGACATGTCAAGTCAAGAAGGGAGCAATCCTTTCTAATTCTTTTCTTTCAGCCGCTGCGGGAACGTGACGCGTTCTCTGCATTGACTTATTCATTCTAGTTAGGCCCCTTGGAACAACGAGATCGACAATCTTGACGAAGTAAAGGTCCAAAGTAATCGTAACATTAGAATTATCAACAGACAAACGCGTTTGGCGTTCTCACTATTTATGGAAGGTTACCTTCCATCCCCTCTCTTCAATCTTTTCCATTTGATATCAAATGAAACTTGAGCGATGAGAGTGTCGATATGGTGTGAACGCGT"`

The problem is that it gets stuck with `+` as seen here:

[image]

Comment: Are you using RStudio? There is an inherent limit in the RStudio console, see here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/does-console-impose-an-upper-limit-on-the-length-of-strings/12872

Comment: Instead of pasting that huge string in the editor, you would be better off saving it in a text file and then reading it into R using something like `readr::read_file('seq.txt')`

Answer (score 1):

In R Studio [Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc) it is written that

```
Command lines entered at the console are limited to about 4095 bytes (not characters).
```

Answer (score 0):

The '+' sign you're seeing usually indicates that a string literal was not closed properly.

For example you might have entered half a line, or did something like

```
mychar <- "ABCD" + <Hit enter here>
```

Otherwise, this probably has to do with some input limit of Rstudio. Using a Jupyter notebook I'm able to read your string just fine:

[image]

Comment: I get the same problem when running R on the terminal directly. Not just specific to Rstudio then.

Comment: String was properly closed.